# Relationship between 2 tables

Tags: ms-access

Sorry for such a vague title - did not know how to name it better.

My problem is as following. I have 2 tables, tbl1, tbl2.

```
tbl1:
tbl1ID
tbl1SomeInf

tbl2:
tbl2ID
tbl1ID (linked by FK)
tbl1SomeInf (copied from tbl1 based on the FK of tbl1ID, basically same row but different column)
tbl2SomeInf
```

What I want to achieve is that I know that tbl1SomeInf will always be associated with tbl1ID and when creating tbl2 I would have to manually keep adding the tbl1SomeInf values, where mistakes can be made.

Question: How do I make a relationship between tbl1SomeInf column from tbl1 and tbl1SomeInf from tbl2. Basically there is already a relationship linking tbl1ID (tbl1) with tbl1ID in tbl2 and the MS Access would not let me create a second relationship. Logically for me it is not a relationship, simply taking tlb1SomeInf from tbl1 which is associated with tbl1ID and copying it to tbl2 into tbl1SomeInf field which is associated by the FK tbl1ID.

If any additional info is required, please ask ^_^.

Edit: Let me put an example. Let's say these are the entries in tbl1:

```
tbl1ID    tbl1SomeInf
9017      ABC
9016      DEF
1140      ABC
1144      KJF
1000      KJF
```

Now tbl2 entries:

```
tbl2ID    tbl1ID    tbl1SomeInf    tbl2SomeInf
AutoID    9017      ABC            irrelevant
.         9017      ABC            irrelevant2
.         9016      DEF            irrelevant3
```

Basically make the tbl1SomeInf fill in automatically based on the FK of tbl1ID.

P.S.: All of this is in MS Access.

Comment: Where/what is your question?

Comment: My bad, explained the actual question a little bit more indepth. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is due to obfuscation or not, but I find myself asking "Why?".  What is the point of tbl1 if all of the information is already contained within tbl2?  I can understand if it was just tbl1ID in tbl2 and you had a 1 to Many relationship between both tablets but it isn't.  That kind of defeats the purpose of even having tbl1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the table1SomeInfo field in the second table at all. Since your table1 and 2 are already have a relationship, you can always access table1's information from table2. providing a correct foreign/linking key.
Just remove the unnecessary field table1SomeInf from table2.

to produce a result like this:

```
tbl2ID    tbl1ID    tbl1SomeInf    tbl2SomeInf
AutoID    9017      ABC            irrelevant
.         9017      ABC            irrelevant2
.         9016      DEF            irrelevant3
```

your query would be something linke this:

```
SELECT tbl2.autoid, tb1.tbl1ID, tbl1.tbl1someinf, tbl2.tbl2someinf
from tb1 inner join tbl2 on tb1.tbl1id= tbl2.tbl1id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I, however, would like to have the tbl1.someinf in the tbl2, because the tbl1.someinf influences the input of tbl2.someinf. Is there a way to lookup a value of tbl1.someinf based on FK tbl1.ID? So that when I'm filling in the tbl2 data I would fill in tbl1ID (say, 9017), it would auto-fill the "ABC" into tbl1someinf and then I fill in tbl2SomeInf value manually.

Comment: I think you need to learn the very basics of database programming this might not only help you to overcome this issue but overall improve your knowledge regarding "rational database" and how they work. good luck.

Comment: Could you recommend some source please?

Answer (score 0):

@krish is correct. Relational Database are useful because they reduce *data redundancy* which is exactly what you're doing. If `tbl1SomeInf` influences `tbl2SomeInf`, then that's business logic - don't make your database concerned with something like that.

I think you used both fields from `tbl1` and the first three from `tbl2` (or all 4), you can create a relationship to reflect that - however I'm not sure how useful it will be.

[image]